# How to count how many pages on a web page using python

Tags: python, web, count

I am trying to make a program (for practice) that count how many chapters and verses in each book of bible.... So let say if I want to know total chapters or verses in book 1 then it will give me the total number. If I only want to know the number of verse in chapter 4 in book 2 then it only gives me the number of verses in that particular chapter. Also, same for the chapters.

So, my logic was to looks for `font class: tk4l` (which is unique font size for the body of context) from this web site:

`http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL=1&CN=1&CV=99`

and if it finds the font class then add 1 to my count of chapters and if fails to find the font class move on to the next book ( `book += 1` ) and do the same thing..

I was going to use :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator



def read_chapters(max_books, max_chapters):
    book=1
    chapter=1
    while chapter <= max_chapters:
         url = 'http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL={}&CN={}&CV=99'.format(book, chapter)
         source_code = requests.get(url).text
         soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
         for bible_text in soup.findAll('font', {'class': 'tk4l'}):
```

and so on...

My question is...

1) how can I print that chapter count?? 
2) I have no idea how I should count the number of verses..

I just started to study Python. Please help me on this.. T.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the HTML content of that page. I recommend using the package `requests`.

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL=1&CN=1&CV=99")
```

To expand on your idea of counting the font usage of tk4l, this could be done by searching for this sub string in the webpagem content:

```
verses = str(page.content).count("font class=tk4l")
print(verses)
```

To get the number of chapters you could proceed in a similar manner with string operations if you identify a unique attribute about the way they are listed.

EDIT: To expand on the number of chapters. This is a little tricky, since the only attribute I immediately notice is, that the chapters are in the pagination. Without using any further packages, you could use some string operations to iterate through the pagination and find the maximum. I am afraid the approach is a bit tricky, but it should work for identifying the maximum number of chapters on the page you mentioned.

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL=1&CN=1&CV=99")
verses = str(page.content).split("http://www.holybible.or.kr/images/l_arrow.gif")[1].split("http://www.holybible.or.kr/images/arrow.gif")[0]
currmax = 0
for i in range(len(verses)):
    if verses[i] == ">":
        if verses[i+2:i+7] == "</a>&":
            if currmax < int(verses[i+1]):
                currmax = int(verses[i+1])
        if verses[i+3:i+8] == "</a>&":
            if currmax < int(verses[i+1:i+3]):
                currmax = int(verses[i+1:i+3])
print(currmax)
```

EDIT 2:
With regular expressions, the same task can be accomplished in a more compact manner:

```
import requests
import re
page = requests.get("http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL=1&CN=1&CV=99")
contents = str(page.content)
x = max(int(i) for i in re.findall(r'>(\d+)</[ab]>&nbsp;', contents))
print(x)
```

Comment: can you please explain me about the page variable? how you split and what it means by [0] ad [1]

Comment: @YunTaeHwang The pagination on the webpage is enclosed by two arrows on that page. Taking page.content as a string means we have the whole content of the webpage as one giant string. Since the pagination elements all end by </a>&nbsp we could just iterate over the whole string, in fact removing everything starting with .split will yield the same result. But sometimes you may want to reduce the data you parse. By splitting at the pagination gifs, we receive a list. With the indexing I extracted exactly the part of the page string containing the chapter numbers.

Comment: I am so sorry,, but can you please explain little bit about the for loop you wrote too.. like verses[i] == ">' ?? hmmmmm if you dont mind..please

Comment: @YunTaeHwang Sure no problem! The range(len(verses)) is the number of characters in the string. I am not iterating over the string directly, since I want to index substrings from the current index. If the letter at verses[i] is ">" then a chapter number is following if </a>&nbsp; comes after the number, which may have 1 or 2 digits (or maybe more). If these 2 conditions are met, the number is extracted and saved if it is larger than the largest found yet. But looking at this today regular expressions are better suited for the task than iterating over the string. I will update my answer.